# Pass data from child component to parent

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to pass information from a child component up to the parent component, and I want this to happen, whenever the information in the child component changes.

What I have so far does not seem to work. The value of config does get updated in the child component, but the value of data never gets updated in the parent component.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is (a cutdown version of) my parent:

```
function App() {
  const version = process.env.VERSION;

  const [data, setData] = React.useState(null)

  const childToParent = (childData) => {
    setData(childData)
  }

  console.log(data)

  return (
          <Container data-testid="containerId" childToParent={childToParent} />
        <Footer data-testid="footerId" version={version} config={data} />
  );
}

export default App;
```

and here is (a cutdown version of) my child:

```
const Container = (childToParent) => {

    // config comes from an API call

    React.useEffect(() => {
        () => childToParent({config});
    }, [config]);

    return (
        <other components/>
    )
}
```

Comment: Are you able to reproduce your issue with the cut-down version of your code?

Comment: The container doesn’t destructure its `props` parameter. Consider approaches like logging or using the debugger to check assumptions like parameter values etc.

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to destructure childToParent from props;

here is the sample code;

```
import React from 'react';

const Container = (props) => {
  const { childToParent } = props;

  const data = 1;
 
  const handleClick = () => {
     childToParent(data);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Trigger Function</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Container;
```

or else destructure directly by using Curly Braces

```
const Container = ({childToParent}) => {}
```